# Is there a simple explanation for why rational plane curves of degree $>2$ are singular?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, rational-curves

Its a well-known result that smooth projective plane curves of degree $d$ have genus $(d-1)(d-2)/2$, so in particular, smooth curves of degree $1$ and $2$ are genus 0, and those of higher degree have positive genus.  It seems like there should be a simple explanation for this in terms of the behavior of dimension 3 subspaces of degree $>2$ polynomials (something about them having too many zeros), using the standard criterion that the map determined by a linear system is an isomorphism if and only if contains functions that distinguish points, and with non-zero derivative at each point, but I have not managed to find it in any reference, or figure out what it is myself.

> Do you have a simple explanation of this fact?

Comment: There *are* many polynomial embeddings $t\mapsto (p(t),q(t))$ of $\mathbb{A}^1$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$. A "simple explanation" would need to account for this fact.

Comment: (One of) the simplest explanation(s) comes from the fact that if $d \geq 3$ then the canonical class is effective. Out of curiosity, why are you looking for an argument involving dimension 3 subspaces of degree $>2$ polynomials?

Comment: When working over $\mathbb{C}$, branched covers do the trick. (In fact, they do the trick even when working with locally-flatly embedded surfaces, not just complex curves.)

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I’m lecturing to a class of undergraduates who don’t know what the canonical class is.  I may just go ahead and explain about it extremely vague terms.

Comment: @BenWebster: you could show that, setting $F(x, \, y)=f(1, \, x, \, y)$, the expression $\omega = dx/F_y = -dy/F_x$ provide a holomorphic differential on the projective curve $f(x, \, y, \, z)=0$ when $d \geq 3$, whereas $\mathbb{P}^1$ has no non-zero holomorphic differentials. This can be done rather quickly and does not require developing all the theory of canonical divisors.

Comment: One must work with the projective plane, otherwise $y=x^n$ with $n \geq 3$ provides a counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing special about rational curves in some sense.

**Proposition**: Given a smooth projective curve $C$, a very ample line bundle $L$ on $C$, and a 3-dimensional subspace $V\subset \Gamma(C,L)$ which is base-point free, the map $\phi:C\to\mathbb{P}(V)$ is an embedding if and only if $V=\Gamma(C,L)$.

The reason is that that $\phi$ is obtained by projection of the embedding $\eta:C\to\mathbb{P}(\Gamma(C,L))$ from the linear projective subspace $\mathbb{P}(W)$ where $W=\Gamma(C,L)/V$. It follows that $\mathbb{P}(W)$ is of codimension 3 in $\mathbb{P}(\Gamma(C,L))$ and thus *must* intersect the secant variety $S(C)$ in $\mathbb{P}(V)$ (which has dimension 3).

---

The response to my comment above is as follows. The tangent variety $T(C)$ is a surface inside $S(C)$. For some curves $C$ in $\mathbb{P}(\Gamma(C,L))$ (such as the rational normal curve), it is *possible* to find $V$ such that $\mathbb{P}(W)$ meets $S(C)$ at *exactly one* point of $T(C)$.

Comment: So maybe to make an elementary argument you could study polynomial embeddings in P3 and their projections and say that if the degree of the plane curve is > 2 then you can extend the embedding in P2 to P3 (by counting degree d monomials). Then you can give an intuitive reason why the secant variety of the P3 embedding is all of P3.

Comment: On the other hand, as @Kapil says, there are examples of maps P1->P2 that are homeomorphic onto their image. There are some examples related to Fibonacci numbers which could be fun to explain.

Comment: It seems there is apparently also nothing special about curves in this nice answer.  It follows from the statement that a smooth projective hypersurface is projectively normal, which follows from the computation of the space of global sections of O(m) restricted to the hypersurface, in section III.1.5 of Shafarevich's BAG1, 2nd edition, pp.163-4.  (take m=1.)

Answer (score 5):

There is an elementary argument based on Bezout count of solutions of an algebraic system. It is given on pages 102-103 of the book ["A Treatise on Algebraic Plane Curves"](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y7WEf6V0XwgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Coolidge.

Comment: Can be viewed online for free at: https://archive.org/details/treatiseonalgebr0000cool

Comment: Thank you, Malek!

Answer (score 3):

After reading the reference suggested by Abdelmalek, I think I have a proof I’m happy with (which is basically the one from the book in more modern language);  I suspect this is also equivalent to the observation in terms of the secant variety from Kapil’s answer.  This is a little more advanced than I was looking for, but I’ve already given my lecture, so this is more for my own satisfaction at this point.

Given three homogeneous polynomials $f_1,f_2,f_3$ of degree $d$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$, we can look for point where this map fails to be injective (we have a node in the image) by looking at whether the section $g_{ij}([X_0:X_1],[Y_0:Y_1])=\frac{f_i(X_0,X_1) f_j(Y_0,Y_1)-f_j(X_0,X_1)f_i(Y_0,Y_1)}{X_0Y_1-X_1Y_0}$ of $\mathcal{O}(d-1)\boxtimes\mathcal{O}(d-1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ vanishes for all $i,j$.  Of course, enough to check this for $i=1$ and $j=2,3$. The multi-Bézout theorem (equivalently, cup product) tells me that there should be $2(d-1)^2$ simultaneous zeros of $g_{12}$ and $g_{13}$ (up to multiplicity).  A simultaneous zero of these corresponds to a cusp if $[X_0:X_1]=[Y_0:Y_1]$ and to a node if $[X_0:X_1]\neq [Y_0:Y_1]$, except when $f_1(X_0,X_1)=f_1(Y_0,Y_1)=0$ and the intersection multiplicity is 1 (in which case, it’s a smooth point).  This final exceptional case accounts for $d^2-d$ points (up to multiplicity).  So, there are $(2(d-1)^2)-d(d-1)=(d-1)(d-2)$ intersection points left that give singularities.  The symmetry under swapping X’s and Y’s tells us that generically we have $(d-1)(d-2)/2$ nodes, as expected from the fact that a smooth curve of this degree has that genus.

Comment: Hi Ben. I figured you would work out the details easily. For a possible future 2nd take on this lesson, maybe one can make this even more elementary as follows. Perhaps counting the generic number of double points exactly can be avoided since we just want it to be $\ge 1$ for $d\ge 3$. Also we don't need multidimensional resultants but just the 1d case, ie, for two nonhomogeneous polynomials in 1 variable, or binary forms. The proof of Bezout for two curves in $P^2$ in Fulton's book is in this spirit, involving the weight of monomials appearing the expansion of the Sylverster determinant.

Comment: A classical argument called the Clebsch transfer principle gives a recipe for reducing the (multidimensional) resultant of two curves plus one line in $P^2$ to the resultant of two binary forms in $P^1$ (basically the third curve which is a line). In that point of view the weight is also the power of the det of a $GL_2$ matrix that comes out of the binary resultant under linear change of variable. Counting points at infinity along certain axes should be elementary with this device.